# PHP - Script repeating when outside foreach statement

Tags: php, sql, mailer

I have an issue with a script I have written that simply selects entries from a database and sends an email to the user to update them on the entries relevant to them. 
The emailer function is working as is the entries filtering out to the individual users. However I'm having a problem where the email is being sent the same number of times the entries appear in the database. The email contains the same content (all 4 entries appear in the same email but it sent 4 times as an example).

this is the mailing script:

```
$data = getData(); 
$uniqueUsers = array();

foreach($data as $item){
$user = $item[1];
$name = $item[3];
$array = array($user, $name);

if(!in_array($array, $uniqueUsers)){
    array_push($uniqueUsers, $array);
};
};
echo print_r($uniqueUsers);
echo "<br>";
echo "<hr>";

foreach($uniqueUsers as $user){
$email = $user[0];
$name = $user[1];
$fullName = explode(" ", $name);
$firstName = $fullName[0];
$updates = "";
echo $email;
echo "<br>";
echo $name;
echo "<br>";
foreach($data as $item){
    if($user[0] == $item[1]){
        $equipmentName = $item[0];
        $approved = $item[2];
        $start = $item[5];
        $end = $item[6];
        $updates .= $approved . " - " . $equipmentName . " (Booked from " . date('l, jS F', strtotime($start)) . " to " . date('l, jS F', strtotime($end)) . ")";
        $updates .= "<br>";
    };
};
echo $updates;
echo "<hr>";

mailer($email, $firstName, $updates);
};
```

This is the getdata() script:

```
mysql_select_db("WBLResources", $con) or die ("Error selecting specified database on mysql server: ".mysql_error());

$query = "SELECT * FROM `Bookings` WHERE `updated` > '" . $date . "'";

$result = mysql_query($query);

$numOfRows = mysql_num_rows($result); 

if($numOfRows < 1){
    exit();
};

for ($i = 0; $i < $numOfRows; $i++) { 
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result); 
    $result_array[$i] = array($row["equipment_name"], 
                              $row["user"], 
                              $row["approved"], 
                              $row["name"], 
                              $row["updated"], 
                              $row["start"], 
                              $row["end"]);
}; 

return $result_array;
};
```

From my analysis the mailer() function should run on uniqueUsers array. This is a snippet of that which I pulled in 10 minutes ago:

```
Array ( 
       [0] => Array ( 
                      [0] => 
                      [1] => ) 
       [1] => Array ( 
                      [0] => ####@###.co.uk 
                      [1] => Username ) 
       [2] => Array ( 
                      [0] => ####@###.co.uk 
                      [1] => Username ) 
       [3] => Array (  
                      [0] => #####@###.co.uk 
                      [1] => Username ) 
       [4] => Array (  
                      [0] => #####@###.co.uk 
                      [1] => Username ) 
       [5] => Array ( 
                      [0] => ######@###.co.uk  
                      [1] => Username ) 
       [6] => Array ( 
                      [0] => #####@###.co.uk 
                      [1] => Username ) )
```

Mailer function:`function mailer($email, $firstName, $updates){

```
$mail = new PHPMailer;

$subject = "Resource Bookings";

$htmlMessageBody = "<div style=font-size:10.0pt;font-family:'Arial',sans-serif;color:black;mso-fareast-language:EN-GB'>Dear " . $firstName . ",<br><br>The following resource bookings have been updated: <br><br>" . $updates . "<br><br>Many thanks,<br>TSW Support</div>";

//$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;                               // Enable verbose debug output

$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = '#######';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = '###@####.co.uk';                 // SMTP username
$mail->Password = '######';
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->Port = 25;                                    // TCP port to connect to
//$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;

$mail->setFrom('####@#####.co.uk', 'TSW Training Group');
$mail->addAddress($email, $firstName);     // Add a recipient
$mail->addReplyTo('#####@######.co.uk', 'TSW Training Group');
$mail->addCC("#####@#####.co.uk", "Support");

$mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = $subject;
$mail->Body    = $htmlMessageBody;
//$mail->AltBody = $plainMessageBody;

if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Message has been sent';
};
```

};`

Any help would be appreciated?

Comment: Your in_array check won't work because each time you create $array, it is a different object even though the values which it takes is the same as the previous one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This logic should fix your problem. Haven't tested it though, so let me know if you hit any errors.

```
    $user_lists = array();
    foreach($data as $item){
    $user = $item[1];
    $name = $item[3];
    $array = array($user, $name);

    if(!in_array($user, $user_lists)){
        array_push($uniqueUsers, $array);
        $user_lists[] = $user;
    };
    };
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for this!
the only issue I have is the mailer isn't working. I'm thinking this is something do witht he second portion where its using for each $uniqueUsers as $user.

should that now be for each $user_lists as $user?

Comment: Can you post your Mailer code also, and you can mark this as answer for the future reference.

Comment: Mailer is now working. not sure why it wasn't originally. Testing the multi-repeat method now but it looks fine so far.

Comment: that's cool ..let me know if you need help with anything else